# Skill tree helper

Tags: java, performance

I'm working on a skill tree calculator for a game and I made a method that checks whether or not it can subtract a point from the skill and then proceeds to do so. Everything is working as it should, however it's very slow when this method is executed in rapid succession (i.e. when 5 points are subtract at the same time). Can anyone help me with this and more important explain why certain things are faster and what to avoid?

```
public void cmdSubtractPoint(int index, SkillTree tree) {

    boolean subtract = false;

    if (this.blueTree.get(index).getInvestedPoints() != 0) {
        //Only subtract a point if the skill isn't empty

        if (index == 0 || index == 1) {
            if ((((this.blueTree.get(0).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(1).getInvestedPoints()) - 1) < 5)
                    && ((this.blueTree.get(2).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(3).getInvestedPoints() +
                    this.blueTree.get(4).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(5).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(6).getInvestedPoints()) != 0)) {
                this.showToast();
            } else if ((((this.blueTree.get(0).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(1).getInvestedPoints()) + this.blueTree.get(2).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(3).getInvestedPoints() - 1) < 10)
                    && ((this.blueTree.get(4).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(5).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(6).getInvestedPoints()) != 0)) {
                this.showToast();
            } else if ((((this.blueTree.get(0).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(1).getInvestedPoints()) + this.blueTree.get(2).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(3).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(4).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(5).getInvestedPoints() - 1) < 15)
                    && ((this.blueTree.get(6).getInvestedPoints()) != 0)) {
                this.showToast();
            } else {
                subtract = true;
            }
        } else if (index == 2 || index == 3) {
            if ((((this.blueTree.get(0).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(1).getInvestedPoints()) + this.blueTree.get(2).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(3).getInvestedPoints() - 1) < 10)
                    && ((this.blueTree.get(4).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(5).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(6).getInvestedPoints()) != 0)) {
                this.showToast();
            } else if ((((this.blueTree.get(0).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(1).getInvestedPoints()) + this.blueTree.get(2).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(3).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(4).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(5).getInvestedPoints() - 1) < 15)
                    && ((this.blueTree.get(6).getInvestedPoints()) != 0)) {
                this.showToast();
            } else {
                subtract = true;
            }
        } else if (index == 4 || index == 5) {
            if ((((this.blueTree.get(0).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(1).getInvestedPoints()) + this.blueTree.get(2).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(3).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(4).getInvestedPoints() + this.blueTree.get(5).getInvestedPoints() - 1) < 15)
                    && ((this.blueTree.get(6).getInvestedPoints()) != 0)) {
                this.showToast();
            } else {
                subtract = true;
            }
        } else if (index == 6) {
                subtract = true;
        }

        if (subtract) {
            this.pointsInBlueTree -= 1;
            this.blueTree.get(index).subtractPoint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Can anyone help me with this and more important explain why certain things are faster and what to avoid.` That comes dangerously close to code understanding instead of review. Have you benchmarked your code to see how slow 'slow' is?

Comment: I have not, but there is a noticeable delay, and I have already posted this to stackOverflow but they told me to post it here.

Comment: Is SkillTree a class you wrote? Maybe its get method speed can be increased. Can you post it too (if it's not too big) ?

Comment: SkillTree is an enumeration of three entries, that shouldn't be the problem. Do you still want me to post it?

Comment: I see an argument called `tree` but I don't see it used in your function.  Perhaps you could explain what your function is supposed to do with that argument?

Comment: This question got an answer on SO, too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834321/can-someone-help-me-make-this-code-more-efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty incomplete, but hopefully it gets at the biggest issue.

## Repetition

Instead of recalculating things and calling `getInvestedPoints()` repeatedly (slow), you can store the values in an array.

```
public void cmdSubtractPoint(int index, SkillTree tree) {

    boolean subtract = false;
    int investedPoints = this.blueTree.get(index).getInvestedPoints();

    int[] numInvested = new int[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < numInvested.Length; i++ ) {
        numInvested[i] = this.blueTree.get(i).getInvestedPoints();
    }

    if (index >= 0 && index < 2) {
        if (numInvested[0] + numInvested[1]...)
    } else if (index < 4) {
        ...
    } else if (index < 6) {
        ...
    } else if (index == 6) {
        ...
    }

    if (subtract) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, rather than adding things every single time (e.g. `get(0).getInvestedPoints + get(1).getInvestedPoints()...`), you can have a single variable serve as the value and alter that based upon if the first test fails.

```
int bottomBounded = numInvested[0] + numInvested[1];
int upperBounded = numInvested[2] + numInvested[3] + 
                   numInvested[4] + numInvested[5] + numInvested[6];
if (bottomBounded - 1 < 5 && upperBounded != 0) {
    this.showToast();
} else {
    // Alter bottomBounded and upperBounded
    if (...)
}
```

Take this with a grain of salt, because it could lead to some nasty nested if-statements.  If you know of a better way to rewrite this that doesn't involve nesting statements, go ahead and do it.

These are just a couple of spots that could be worked on.  There are more, but given the structure of your code trying to do a lot more might make it difficult to read.

## Smaller Things

- In the code I posted above, you'll notice I replaced things with a single less-than condition rather than two checks for equality.  It's a small thing and not too big a deal, but in the future you can take advantage of the fact that else if implies mutual exclusivity between its conditions; that is, only one can be true.
- Don't repeat yourself--when `index == 0 || index == 1`, there are 2 possible outcomes: `this.showToast()` and `subtract = true`.  See if you can rewrite your code so that you don't repeat `this.showToast()`.
- Try to keep your lines < 80 characters long; it helps with readability so people don't have to scroll to see the rest of a line of code.